# EF Core Query between two join entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following entities:

- Volunteer
- Job
- Talent

And following many-to-many join entities:

- JobVolunteer
- JobTalent
- TalentVolunteer

Both a Job and a Volunteer have multiple Talents. I want to search all Jobs where their Talents are the same as the Talents of the Volunteer.

How can I do this? At the moment I'm using the following code, but as a result I get all Jobs which contain one (or more) of the required Talents. I want to only find the Jobs where the Volunteer has (at least) all of the required Talents.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FindJobs(int? id)
{
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var volunteer = await _context.Volunteers
                .Include(v => v.TalentVolunteers)
                    .ThenInclude(v => v.Talent)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.VolunteerID == id);

            if (volunteer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var jobs = new List<Job>();
            var talentVolunteers = new HashSet<int>(volunteer.TalentVolunteers.Select(t => t.TalentID));

            foreach (var talent in _context.JobTalents)
            {
                if (talentVolunteers.Contains(talent.TalentID))
                {
                    var selectedJob = _context.Jobs
                        .Include(t => t.JobTalents)
                            .ThenInclude(v => v.Talent)
                        .SingleOrDefault(t => t.JobID == talent.JobID);

                    jobs.Add(selectedJob);
                }
            }

            var volunteersFindJobsViewModel = _mapper.Map<Volunteer, VolunteersFindJobsViewModel>(volunteer);

            volunteersFindJobsViewModel.Jobs = jobs;

            return View(volunteersFindJobsViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Option**

Select all talent Ids for the volunteer and store them in a list/array and then use this list in the conditional statement of the Job

```
var volunteerTalentIds = _context.TalentVolunteer.Where(a=>a.VolunteerId == {yourVolunteerId}).Select(a=>a.TalentId).ToList();

var selectedJobs = _context.Jobs.Include(a=>a.JobTalents).Where(a=>a.JobTalents.All(b=>volunteerTalentIds.Contains(b.TalentId))).ToList();
```

**Second Option**

Do a long chain of Joins

```
var selectedJobs = (from job in _context.Jobs 
join jobTalent in _context.JobTalents on jobTalent.JobId equals job.JobId 
join volunteerTalent in _context.VolunteerTalents on jobTalent.TalentId equals volunteetTalent.TalentId 
where volunteerTalent.VolunteerId = {yourVolunteerId} select job).ToList();
```

Comment: The First option doesn't seem to work (you can't do Where on Include in EF Core I think?). I solved it by making a third between query for the jobTalentIds.
However, both methods still give me all jobs where only one (or more) Talents match. I would like to only get the Jobs where (at least) all the Talents match between Job and Volunteer.

Comment: You can use Where on include, but in case the included property is a List, you need to user `.Any` and add sub query there to check, Glad to here that you've solved it

Comment: How exactly would you rephrase that with the .Any ?
Your second solution works but gives me all Jobs where one Talent matches while I would only like the Jobs where all Talents match. Any idea how to handle that?
Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the answer, i think this is how you do it using `.Any`

Comment: Indeed, your option 1 works now too. Thanks!
The only problem is these solutions give me all Jobs where one Talent of the volunteer matches with the required Talents from the Job. I would only like the Jobs where a Volunteer has all Talents required by the Job. Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, lets trace it down (option 1 for example) you have selected all volunteer talent IDs, and when querying the job, you've made a conditional statement that "If any TalentId of the Job existed in the list of Ids that we retrieved from volunteer" the statement will be true, if you can share a link to the source code i can debug it and know exactly where is the issue.

Comment: Ok, I seemed to have solved it. In option 1 I replaced .Any with .All and now I only get the jobs where all Talents match.
Seems logical to me now, but I had never used .All before.
Thanks for the help!